# What is the Magit 2 way to do what wazzup used to?

Tags: magit, git

I used to use Magit <2's wazzup mode to survey unmerged branches or general branch divergence.  What's the right way to do that or some other way to view unmerged branches in Magit 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `v2.1` the "branch manager" and "wazzup" were merged into one mode. Such changes are usually being announced in the release notes.

> The new Refs buffer combines the features of the old Wazzup and
>   Branch Manager buffers into one, more powerful and efficient
>   synthesis.  For each reference, cherries can be shown by expanding
>   the ref section, but unlike in the Wazzup buffer, the cherries are
>   not calculated until the expansion happens, making it vastly more
>   efficient.  Besides local and remote branches, the buffer now also
>   lists tags, and users can add additional sections listing other
>   refs, e.g., stashes.  The format of refs headers is now
>   customizable.

The new key binding is <kbd>y</kbd>.

By default the number of commits a branch has in addition to those in the current branch are not shown, that would be to expensive when there exist many refs with many additional commits. You can show them using <kbd>C-y</kbd>, or you can customize `magit-refs-show-commit-count`.

Comment: I don't understand from your answer how this allows me to "survey unmerged branches or general branch divergence"?

Comment: To the left of some branches numbers will appear. Those numbers are the number of commits which are in the respective branch but not in the branch prefixed with a star. When you press `TAB` on such a branch, then you will also get a list of those commits.